# How do I get rid of a corrupted filename ( / inside ) in ext4 home mount point?

Tags: filesystem

```
/home sudo ls -l rubish
ls: can't access rubish/tongue/gif: none file of folder of that kind
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?              ? tongue/gif
```

I could move the folder to the top of /home but I can't move it outside another partition:

```
sudo mv rubish /svr
mv: unable to evaluate "rubish/tongue/gif": none file of folder of that kind
```

Thank you

Comment: How about `rm -rf rubish`?

Comment: Did you see the strange file's attributes?
`sudo rm -rf rubish
rm: unable to remove "rubish": the folder is not empty`sudo mv

Comment: Did you see the strange file's attributes?
`sudo rm -rf rubish
rm: unable to remove "rubish": the folder is not empty`

Comment: Try to boot a Live USB/CD and run `fsck -f /dev/<partition>`.

Comment: This did the job. The hardest was build the LiveUSB. In my particular car where I first reached to move the folder+file the top of the tree, I ran the 'e2fsck -f' online (which is not recommended I know, but I was too disgusted not to be able to build the USB tool). The command found the illegal caracter error and proposed to change it in a dot. I said yes, then no to all other questions. In the end I found twice a file tongue.gif in the folder. I don't remember how I removed them or the folder. As e2fsck still reported other errors I insisted in building the USB, reached with the Gparted Live

Comment: and the manuel creation (.zip + commands, see the doc). Later I tried another way: reboot in recovery mode, login, cd to / , unmount /home then (just to see) e2fsck -f /dev/sdc1 then reboot. Thank you Eric